# Remove email Updates on Case Feed

Tags: case, feeditem

I have an email action on case. 
When a user sends an email, the details about the email are displayed in the Feed.
I would like to remove the details from the feed. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome. Could you be a little specific on what you mean by remove the details? Are you looking to have no feed entry at all or just some info? A screenshot with the stuff you want removed crossed out would be helpful too.

Comment: Currently when am sending an email via quick action.  The following is displayed on my Record feed.

 — Amira to John Smith. Only sent an email.

To:JoHmsmith@gmail.com Subject:RE: test

I would like to remove all the details.
If i send an email, nothing should appear on my feed.
Thanks